# Manipulate arrays into different formats

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I have a Doctrine Query

```
$qb->select(['i.name', 'io.year', 'count(io) AS population'])
    ->from('AppBundle:IOxxx', 'io')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:Iyyy', 'i', 'WITH' , 'io.country = i.id')
    ->groupBy('i.name')
    ->addGroupBy('io.year');
```

that returns an array with with data grouped by country name and year like this (in this case I only have one country for now, but extra countries will just be added with the same principle);

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '1960'
      'population' => int 133
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '1970'
      'population' => int 203
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '1980'
      'population' => int 298
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '1990'
      'population' => int 378
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '2000'
      'population' => int 450
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Africa' (length=6)
      'year' => string '2010'
      'population' => int 560
```

I am trying to create two arrays from this array, one with the Countries, and one that holds the remaining data;

The countries array should look like this (making use of the name);

```
$countries = ['Africa', 'AnotherCountry', 'MoreCountries'];
```

And the remaining data should look like this;

```
$series = [
    ['name' => '1960', 'data' => [133, 11, 22]],
    ['name' => '1970', 'data' => [203, 11, 22]],
    ['name' => '1980', 'data' => [298, 11, 22]],
    ['name' => '1990', 'data' => [378, 11, 22]],
    ['name' => '2000', 'data' => [450, 11, 22]],
    ['name' => '2010', 'data' => [560, 11, 22]],
];
```

Where the first value in data corresponds with the first country in countries, and so on...

I'm trying to organize this for graph purposes like you can see in this example from highcharts:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic (then click on 'view options' to see how it's configured)

Can somebody please help me? It would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update** with what I tried:

I have tried to go through a loop:

```
$countries = [];
$series = [];
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $countries[] = $item['name'];
    $series[]['name'] = $item['status'];
    $series[]['data'][] = $item['number_of_orders'];
}
```

But obviously now I get all names together, like Africa 6 times, but I need it only once.

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Africa' (length=6)
```

and for the series I get:

```
array (size=14)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string '1960' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'data' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 133
```

instead of 'data' directly next to 'name' in the first array instead of its own array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be done with two loops like these (`$data` is your query result):

```
$years = [];
$countries = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!in_array($row['name'], $countries)) {
        $countries[] = $row['name'];
    }

    $years[$row['year']][$row['name']] = $row['population'];
}

$result = [];
foreach ($years as $year => $data) {
    $row = [
        'name' => $year, 
        'data' => array_fill(0, count($countries), 0)
    ];

    foreach ($data as $country => $population) {
        $row['data'][array_search($country, $countries)] = $population;
    }

    $result[] = $row;
}
```

You would need the variables `$countries` and `$result`